# How to Navigate Database 1 by 1 using a button like a Queue System

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm setting up A QueueSystem and I have a set of buttons of "Next", "Previous", "Transfer" and "Finish" buttons. 
How can I navigate my database Record and show it to my View.

Example:

When I click the "Next" button it will show the first queue on my database, so it will show like "A001", then when I click the "Next" Button again it will show the second record; "A002".

I wonder how can I possibly make this happen, I need references and suggestions, thankyou.

Here is my model :

```
public class TellerScreen
{
    public int TellerScreenId { get; set; }
    public string Current { get; set; }
    public int WaitingNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my button for next :

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "BtnNext", null,@*new { index = Model.NextIndex },*@new AjaxOptions
                            {
                            HttpMethod = "GET",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            UpdateTargetId = "current",
                            LoadingElementId = "loading",
                            OnBegin = "ClearResults",
                            }, new { @class = "Middle-next dim btn btn-large-dim", @id = "Link1" })
```

Here is my controller:

```
    public PartialViewResult BtnNext(int current = 0)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        var model = db.Queues.OrderBy(x => x.QueueNumber).Skip(current).Take(1);
        return PartialView("_queuenumber", model);
    }
```

Comment: Transfer and Finish button I dont know, but for Next and Previous, you can have a global variable, when click next add 1, click previous minus 1, and pass this variable to btnNext function, maybe change function name is better.

Comment: in my code how can I add 1 and minus 1? can u show me? pls

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PagedList` library with the number per page is only one.

Reference more at

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/paging-and-sorting-in-mvc4-using-pagedlist/

Nuget

https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/